# "Set as StartUp Project" not changing deploy configuration in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm working at a colleagues PC. When I right click on a .Net Gadgeteer 4.2 project in our solution and select "Set as StartUp Project" I expect Visual Studio to set the build configurations so that the new start-up project is deployed to the device on start, as it does on my PC. But instead I need to open the configuration manager and manually deselect the previous start-up project and select the new one. Why? How can I swap (back) to using Visual Studio to manage deployment without the additional step in the configuration manager?

========== EDIT ==========

@john-saunders comment below makes me think I've misworded my question.

I have a solution containing multiple projects, many of which are .Net Gadgeteer projects.

On most of my machines if I right click on Project A in the Solution Explorer and select Set as StartUp Project then when I debug the solution (i.e. hit F5) Project A and any of its required dependencies are built and deployed to the Gadgeteer device and the debugger gets attached. If I then right click on Project B in the Solution Explorer and select Set as StartUp Project then when I debug the solution Project B and any of its required dependencies are built and deployed to the Gadgeteer device.

But on one machine this is not happening. Instead when I right click on Project B in the Solution Explorer and select Set as StartUp Project when I debug the solution Project A is deployed to the Gadgeteer device. To ensure that Project B is instead deployed I have to manually edit the configuration.

Why? How do I get this one machine to behave like the others?

Comment: Why would you expect this?

Comment: Because it's the usual behaviour on my other machines. I do not normally have to touch the configuration manager at all.

Comment: You have some special machines, then. I've never seen this behavior.

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused about "Set as StartUp Project". What do you expect it to do John?

Comment: It sets which project will start when you press F5.

Comment: Exactly, that is exactly what I expect. And yet on this one machine if I select Project B to be the start-up project Project A is started unless I first edit the configuration.